# Why the SonarQube server fails to start with following error message "Database relates to a more recent version"

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Sonar 3.7.2 with JTDS driver for MSSQL database. While starting the sonar in windows gives following error:

```
2015.06.26 02:54:53 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  SonarQube Server / 3.7.2 / 1feffde9f95897aa000a7123ba54a8c8757b40d8
2015.06.26 02:54:53 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://enbuild03/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor
2015.06.26 02:54:54 **ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings**.
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.
2015.06.26 02:54:57 INFO  jruby.rack  jruby 1.6.8 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-09-18 1772b40) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_43) [Windows Server 2008 R2-amd64-java]
2015.06.26 02:54:57 INFO  jruby.rack  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
```

I'm stuck here since sonar server not even starting because of the above bold error...

Any help will be appreciated ???

Comment: It somehow seems that a newer version of sonar has been run against the db you created. Can you try deleting this DB, create a new one and see if that works?

Comment: Is there any file storing this type of information (db relates to a specific version of sonar) ??

Comment: In that case, I can simply delete this file and restart Sonar.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any file. You can just as well create a new DB and try connecting with that..

Comment: Cool, I've pasted my comment below, can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It somehow seems that a newer version of sonar has been run against the db you created. Can you try creating a new DB and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

If you have run some latest version of sonarqube and then downgraded the sonarqube; you are likely to get this error, if both versions are mapped to same database.
If you view the database there will be some tables in that db, once you wipe out the content of DB and restart sonarqube this error will be gone.